# How to get one thread to wait for another thread?chapter 2

Tags: java, multithreading

actualy i have this problem...i have class first i call thread t1..i want thread t1 is completed execute then thread t2 under looping for  will be executed..i call that is Thread t2..like code below :

```
for(int j=0 ;j < idW.length ;j++){
     webtext = d.getWebText(idW[j]); 
     ThreadPrepo tpo = new ThreadPrepo(webtext, host[j%jumhost], "server", 1099, idW[j]);//hozstnya  
     Thread t1 = new Thread(tpo);
     t1.start();

      }
ThreadD td=new ThreadD;
Thread t2=new Thread(t2);
t2.start();
```

so ThreadD t2 will executed after thread t1 complete executed..so thread t2 must wait until t1 completed executed... so i asked what i supposed to do to solve that????

Comment: This will not compile `Thread t2=new Thread(t2)` (unless you are doing something very odd). Post your _real_ code.

Comment: yes.. i give title chapter 2 because i need solution to solve this problem

Comment: @BoristheSpider that's is my real code...so in your opinion what supposed i do?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use join method on Thread t1 so that the execution will wait till the execution of t1 will complete.

```
t1.join();
```

Comment: in my code above where i must put t1.join()...
I want put t1.join() outside for..how do that?
please help me to give example

Comment: It depend on your task.You have declare the Thread inside the loop.I dnt know y you need to declare Thread everytime the loop run.You can declare the Thread t1 outside and same use join outside too

Comment: i declacre the thread in loop because so i can get divide the jobs off the computer with ip [host[j % jumhost]..because in this ThreadPrepo class there are rmi process...

Comment: @zorro then you need to use the join inside the loop bcoz thread is declare inside it.

Comment: This will cause the program to run in a synchronous manner. You will wait for each thread to finish in the loop thereby removing any benefit from the threads. Don't do this.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I also suggest the same what u said right now,but its his requirement.

Comment: No, the OP's requirement is to wait for _all_ threads to finish not _each_ thread to finish. This is the definition of concurrency - doing multiple things at once.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Please check my comment.'It depend on your task.' which is just above.I already suggest to use join outside the loop

Comment: Your comment is also wrong and shows a fundamental misunderstanding of threading. It also deserves a downvote. The OP wants to do `dW.length` tasks _in parallel_ which is why the worker threads are declared in a loop. The OP then wants to wait for all those `dW.length` to jointly finish. This should take as long as it takes the longest task to finish. Both your suggestions make the solution synchronous rather than concurrent - taking as long as it takes the sum of those tasks to finish. Can you see the difference?

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a reference to `t1` to `t2`, and the code that `t2` is running needs to call `t1.join()`.

Comment: in my code above where i must put t1.join()... I want put t1.join() outside for..how do that?

Comment: please give example ... T^T

Comment: @zorro you are creating multiple threads in the loop. do you want to Run the t2 thread after all the threads running in the loop are finished

Comment: @chrylis thats right...yes i want to do like that...how can I do it?

Comment: @chrylis how chrylis?

Comment: @zorro answered below using countdown latch

Comment: @Edge countdown latch?can u give example or link refrence....

Answer (score 0):

use synchronized method or statements to solve this problem in which the change in one thread guarantees the update in second one.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html

Comment: synchronized will not wait the thread t2 executuion

Comment: @deepak can u give me example with code so i can more understand...

Comment: but it will not execute the second thread until the first one completes it's execution if both are synchronized.

Comment: @zorro please follow the link i have given it has also the examples.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use raw `Thread`s, use an [`ExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html):

```
final int[] idW = null;
final ExecutorService es = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
final Collection<Future<?>> fs = new LinkedList<>();
for (int j = 0; j < idW.length; j++) {
    webtext = d.getWebText(idW[j]);
    ThreadPrepo tpo = new ThreadPrepo(webtext, host[j % jumhost], "server", 1099, idW[j]);
    fs.add(es.submit(tpo));
}
for (final Future<?> f : fs) {
    f.get();
}
final Future<?> f2 = es.submit(t2);
es.shutdown();
```

Submit all the first set of tasks to the service, this returns a `Future`. Keep the futures as they are a handle on the task.

Next loop over the futures and call `get()` - this will wait for that task to complete. When this loop is done all tasks are done.

Finally submit the other task to the service.

Don't forget to `shutdown()` the service after submitting the last task, this will cause it to kill all the threads it creates when the last submitted task is complete.

There are plenty of [tutorials on the internet](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/executorservice.html) explaining the `ExecutorService` API in more detail.

Comment: this method u create not use thread?

Comment: @zorro maybe read some of the links I have posted? Or course it does, otherwise it wouldn't really be a solution. It just uses threads properly.

Comment: thanks for our answer ...i will try...

Answer (score 0):

use Countdown latch

```
private CountDownLatch _latch= new CountDownLatch(idW.length);

 for(int j=0 ;j < idW.length ;j++){
   webtext = d.getWebText(idW[j]); 
    ThreadPrepo tpo = new ThreadPrepo(webtext, host[j%jumhost], "server", 1099, idW[j], _latch);//hozstnya  
    Thread t1 = new Thread(tpo);
    t1.start();
  }
  _latch.await();
  ThreadD td=new ThreadD();
  Thread t2=new Thread(td);
  t2.start();
```

pass the _latch to run() function of the loop threads _latch.countdown() at the end of the run() method.